# SQL NESTED Query Optimization

Tags: postgresql, optimization

I am running two sql queries say,

```
select obname from table1 where obid = 12

select modname from table2 where modid = 12
```

Both are taking very less time, say 300 ms each.

But when I am running:

```
select obname, modname 
from (select obname from table1 where obid = 12) as alias1, 
(select modname from table2 where modid = 12) as alias2
```

It is taking 3500ms. Why is it so?

Comment: How many rows are the two queries returning?

Comment: First of all you are comparing 2 queries to 1,in execution queries are not like apples just add the times together and its done

Comment: Why don't you use `UNION ALL`

Comment: The second query is returning only one row

Answer (score 1):

In general, putting two *scalar* queries in the `from` clause is not going to affect performance.  In fact, from an application perspective, one query may be faster because there is less overhead going back and forth to the database.  A scalar query returns one column and one row.

However, if the queries are returning multiple rows, then your little comma is doing a massive Cartesian product (which is why I always use `CROSS JOIN` rather than a comma in a `FROM` clause).  In that case, all bets are off, because the data has to be processed after the results start returning.

Comment: Even cross join is taking the same time for me...because the second query is returning only one row